# Will transit time render Mars disease free?

Tags: mars, time, forward-contamination

It's going to take us a few months to travel to mars in our spaceships.  Will the relatively small size of the ship combined with a few months of "isolation" result in Mars being disease free until either we build bigger ships or faster propulsion?

Comment: Lots of things (e.g. anthrax) can survive in spore form forever.  It only takes one teensy not-sterile thing, like a person's skin, to carry some bad stuff along.

Comment: You may get sick from bacteria living normally on the surface or inside your body. For instance a bladder infection from escheria coli living in your lower intestine.

Answer (score 5):

Not completely, for a number of reasons, but in theory there should be less disease than on Earth.

Some diseases last for a very long time, like AIDS. Things like the flu will have a really hard time making it to Mars. Some diseases have few symptoms, which makes them easier to hide. Lastly, things in space just tend to end up really germy.

As a whole, with a bit of work, Mars could remain mostly disease free, however, proper precautions still must be taken.

For some comparison, the voyage time from Europe to North America was about 3 months early on. Disease still managed to cross that gap. No doubt the same thing would happen going to Mars, although I still suspect there would be less colds/ flu/ etc on Mars than on Earth.

Comment: What is supporting your conclusion? Also, what would be the pre-launch quarantine time for mars settlers as part of the "bit of work".

Comment: For one example, varicella-zoster virus will have no trouble making it to Mars. Most people who've had chickenpox will carry it in latent form for the rest of their lives, and can transmit it if it ever reactivates as shingles.

Comment: Those are some interesting additional bits. Many diseases could be cured by the distance, but as you mentioned, certainly not all of them.

Comment: @eckes: Some expeditions to Mir and the ISS have lasted longer than a Mars trip would.  Yet both stations had a thriving community of microbial flora, including various *Staph* and *Strep* species that act as opportunistic infections (normally living on hard surfaces and human skin, but dangerous when growing in the wrong parts of the body).

Comment: Not to mention that there are a myriad of species in the human microbiome https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4848870/  Any one of these could mutate to cause a disease.  Indeed, some dying off or becoming imbalanced WRT others can cause diseases.  Consider E. coli, for one notable instance: https://www.cdc.gov/ecoli/general/index.html

Comment: No sources and 4 upvotes?